# Elementary OS on Intel Atom?

Tags: system-installation, intel, 32-bit

Is there any way to install Elementary on 6 year old Samsung N510 with Intel Atom?

Specs:
Processor: Intel Atom N270 1.6 GHz
 Graphics adapter: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M (G) / ION (LE), Core: 450 MHz, shared memory,  Forceware 186.19/XP
 Memory: 1024 MB, DDR2 PC2-6400, 1 Slot, max. 2GB
 Display: 1.6 inch 16:9, 1366x768 pixel, SEC 3052, glossy: no
 Mainboard: Nvidia MCP79MX (9400M G)
 Storage: Samsung SpinPoint M5S HM160HI, 160 GB, 5400 rpm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately elementary OS 0.4 Loki requires a 64-bit CPU, however the Atom N270 is 32-bit. All of the Loki packages are only bit for 64-bit, so installing Ubuntu and then adding the elementary repos is not a viable solution.

elementary OS 0.3 Freya, the previous elementary release, was the last to feature a 32-bit installer. You can download it by pasting the following magnet link into a BitTorrent client:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0a36a61cb46fc1444c95eb62185b777d65362ca9&dn=elementaryos-freya-i386.20150411.iso&tr=https%3A%2F%2Fashrise.com%3A443%2Fphoenix%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80%2Fannounce&ws=http%3A%2F%2Fsuberb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net%2Fproject%2Felementaryos%2Fstable%2Felementaryos-freya-i386.20150411.iso&ws=http%3A%2F%2Fignum.dl.sourceforge.net%2Fproject%2Felementaryos%2Fstable%2Felementaryos-freya-i386.20150411.iso&ws=http%3A%2F%2Fheanet.dl.sourceforge.net%2Fproject%2Felementaryos%2Fstable%2Felementaryos-freya-i386.20150411.iso&ws=http%3A%2F%2Fcitylan.dl.sourceforge.net%2Fproject%2Felementaryos%2Fstable%2Felementaryos-freya-i386.20150411.iso)
```

You won't receive feature updates for Freya, only security patches (making it safe for continued use).

You might like to take a look at installing [regular Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), or the more lightweight [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) - both of which provide 32-bit installers.